# Let's contemplate silence

Tags: discussion, challenge

This week's [challenge](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge) was suggested by [Soldarnal](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/193/68):

> **Silence**
>
> I could try to be clever and tie this theme to some part of the calendar, but mostly I thought of it because [Psalm 131](http://www.esvbible.org/search/psalm+131/) came up in my reading recently and I began to think about how much the theme runs through Scriptures: people asking that God would not be silent, God asking that people would be.

To me, this is an excellent time of year to focus on silence as opposed to the chaos that most of us are surrounded by.

"So how do we ask questions about *silence*?" [Tom thought](http://thinks.com/words/tomswift.htm).

I use the challenge as a jumping-off point.  You might search the Bible for words like [silence](http://www.esvbible.org/search/silence/) or [quiet](http://www.esvbible.org/search/quiet/) and read whatever passages turn up.  Conversely, you could look up the opposite idea ([commotion](http://www.esvbible.org/search/commotion/), [noise](http://www.esvbible.org/search/noise/), etc.).  Then something about one of the passages might interest, confuse, or surprise you.  From there, compose a question (remembering our [guidelines](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/a-new-guideline-for-doctrine-in-questions-what-do-you-think)) and [ask it](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  I'd appreciate it if you'd tag it [silence](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silence) and post a comment that links back to the challenge.  These might be cleaned up later if they don't add much to the question, but in the meantime they could spark some interest in this enterprise.

---

If you'd like to help us pick the challenge for next week, drop an answer at [this question](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/68).