# Let's rest Biblically

Tags: discussion, challenge

By an amazing coincidence, this is the 7<sup>th</sup> [challenge topic](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge) I've suggested.  "[Challenge ideas](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/194/68)" isn't a challenge itself, but a place for us to collect and vote on topics.  My favorite remaining idea is from [Ray](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/194/68):

> **Rest**
>
> Rest seems to be a theme throughout the Bible, played out in different way, from God's rest in creation, to the rest promised to the Israelites, to a rest that believers have in Christ.
>
> Where else is "rest" mentioned? How do these tie together?

---

It's especially pressing on me as I contemplate going home for Christmas to be with my family.  As a result, I might be taking a rest from the site.  (On the other hand, the site might be an escape for me. Who knows?  ;-)  I'm also thinking of stepping down from issuing the challenges for a while.  The idea is clearly a [good one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/own-your-community-2/), but I don't want to get into a rut myself (feeling obligated to make this weekly post).  In addition, I hope someone will step up and take some more ownership of the community.

Personally, I'm going to be doing a little more resting, but I hope that *you* will be thinking of questions to ask about Biblical Rest.