# Five Scroll Challenge

Tags: discussion, challenge

It's been a while since we last took up a [challenge](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/challenge-ideas). Given the not-too-long-ago release of the [asking day badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), it seems like a good a time as any to propose one. So here goes.

For the month of August here, let's try to ask some good questions about the five scrolls:

[song-of-songs](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-of-songs), [ruth](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruth), [lamentations](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lamentations), [ecclesiastes](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecclesiastes), [esther](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esther)

At least a couple of these tags are sorely lacking questions. On a couple of others it seems like we have some key questions, but there's room still for an authoritative answer. Anyone want to join me in this?

Comment: This is a great idea - and I'm grateful for the chipping away at my ignorance too, I'd never heard of [five scrolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Megillot) :)

Comment: Trivia: *Song of Songs.* The **only** book of the Bible that has never had a unit study in the Assemblies of God adult curriculum.

Answer (score 5):

I like it. Since the [Five Megillot](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10557-megillot-the-five) (also described in the *[Encyclopedia Judaica](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0018_0_17898.html)*) are "festival scrolls" in Judaism (and have status as "liturgical readings") they have a collective identity in that context which is lost (for the most part) in Christian communities. Interesting, then, that this "collection" was the first of the fascicles of the *[Biblia Hebraica Quinta](http://www.scholarly-bibles.com/products/Original-Texts/Old-Testament/Hebrew/Biblia-Hebraica-Quinta-BHQ2.html)* to appear.

It would be good (assuming this takes off!) to have a [five-megillot](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-megillot) (tag) much as we have one for [torah](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah), for example. (Do you think?)

*Caveat lector!* Some of the questions I can think of -- especially relating to the Megillot as a group -- might fall foul of our standard guidelines for what counts as "on topic". Should we use this meta thread to generate some examples that would be acceptable given BH.SE conventions?

Comment: I like the idea of getting ideas rolling here.

Comment: I second @FrankLuke

Comment: I'm all in favor of a five-megillot tag. We've done that in the past with these kind of challenges. And if we end up not finding it useful in the long run, we can remove the tag later.

Answer (score 4):

### Question for Lamentations

Traditionally, *Lamentations* has been attributed to Jeremiah, the reason it follows Jeremiah in the Christian ordering of the Old Testament. However, Jeremiah is no longer generally accepted as an author.<sup>1</sup> [Others](http://www.insight.org/resources/bible/lamentations.html) say there is much internal and external evidence to link it to Jeremiah. What evidence is there for and against Jeremiah as the author?

---

<sup>1</sup>Hayes, John H. "The Songs of Israel". In McKenzie, Steven L.; Graham, Matt Patrick. *The Hebrew Bible Today: An Introduction to Critical Issues.* Westminster John Knox Press, 1998. 168.

Comment: On main: [Who wrote Lamentations?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12897)

Answer (score 4):

#### Question(s) for Song of Songs:

- [“but” or “and”? How to understand the first conjunction in Song of Songs 1:5?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12922/2215)

Comment: On main: [“Black but beautiful” or “Black and beautiful” in Song of Songs?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12922/black-but-beautiful-or-black-and-beautiful-in-song-of-songs)

Answer (score 1):

#### Question(s) for Ecclesiastes:

- [How did Ecclesiastes come to be associated with Sukkot?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13142/how-did-ecclesiastes-come-to-be-associated-with-sukkot)

Curious how this question in particular floats here. I'd like to see these as on-topic, but I could also see it being considered a better fit for the Judaism site, since it has to do with their liturgical use.